# Using FileGetMimeType() with uploads to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I have so far allowed users to upload images to my server and then used CF's `FileGetMimeType()` function to determine if the MIME type is valid (.e.g jpg)

The problem is that `FileGetMimeType()` wants a full path to the file on the server to work. Amazon S3 is just a URL of where the image is stored. In order to get `FileGetMimeType()` to work, I have to first upload the image to Amazon S3 then download it again using CFHTTP and then determine the file type. This seems way less efficient than the old way.

So why not just upload to my own server first, determine the MIME type, and then upload to S3 right? I can't do that because some of these files are going to be huge with thousands of users uploading at the same time. We're talking videos as well as images.

Is there an efficient way to upload files to an external server i.e. Amazon S3 and then get the MIME type somehow without having to download the file all over again? Can it be done on S3's end?

Comment: ColdFusion 11 lets you read the mime type from an image URL. Is this not the case anymore? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31662415/5000465   ---- Edit: Tested, you can still do it. Just feed it the location of your file in the S3 bucket.

Comment: I wouldn't put much, if any, faith in MIME types. Listen to Pete's talk and look at some of his suggestions about dealing with file uploads.  https://teratech.com/020-secrets-of-high-security-coldfusion-code-with-pete-freitag-transcript/

Comment: On Lucee this function will work on s3 paths. However, I found major problems with this function because it opens the file and validates it, which is done incredibly inefficiently on large files. In Lucee I believe you can tell it to look at the filename only, but I had problems with that too. Instead, I wrote my own function with a big switch stmt that does the trick.

Comment: @TRose well turns out you're right. it doesnt say in the docs that it accepts URLs so i never knew it was possible!